# How to stop a Service from PreferenceFragment class

Tags: android

I have a `PreferenceFragment` class call pf, and a `Service` class call hdservice.

How to stop `Service` from `Fragment`? Is that possible?

Comment: Be clear with your codes>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment's getActivity gets you the activity in which this frgament is hosted and then you can run stopService on it. e.g

```
getActivity().stopService(new Intent(...));
```

Comment: @ThomasKilian there ya go

Comment: getActivity() returns null sometimes. How to handle that?